# Why won't this htaccess exclude condition work?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm forcing https on all pages on our site, but because of complications with some old plugins we use (needing to connect over http), I need to set up an exception to the https forcing for one directory.

I can't quite work it out though. The rule I think should work is giving me a 403 error.

Can someone have a look?

I've got a bunch of stuff for redirecting non-www to www:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain1.site.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain2.site.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Then there's the https forcing:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But if I add another condition to exclude the directory from this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/sub-subdir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I get an error where I see the content from my 404 page, but the URL is https://www.site.com/403.shtml - but I don't have a 403.shtml in my web root. (This is a WHM/cPanel-driven server)

Comment: You have no other rules that has an `F` flag or anything that's like `Deny from All`? A 403 means you've made the request forbidden, it's not an error with mod_rewrite

Comment: No other such rules. Just mime types, expires header stuff, and redirects. I have edited my original question to further explain the error I'm experiencing, as it's kinda weird.